# Remove microseconds and make seconds zero in datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, format

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `"date"`, I want to go from this format:

`2018-12-11 15:26:04.877`

Into a `datetime`, where there are no microseconds and all seconds are zero:

`2018-12-11 15:26:00`

What I have done so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
dfdf=pd.read_excel('datefix.xlsx')

print(df.dtypes)
df.date =pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce')
print(df.date)
df["date"].datetime.replace(microsecond=0)
```

But I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Is there another way to get to the outcome desired?

Comment: `df["date"]` is a portion of your dataframe. It is of type `pd.Series`. If you want to replace each element in the series, you'll have to first dig deeper into the dataframe.

Comment: Try the `map` method to apply `datetime.replace...` to each element of the column.

Comment: `df["d"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x:time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` gives me the format but not over each element of the column, it prints todays date with time, could you tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.replace` use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` on the datetime object.

If you have a column of datetime objects, apply the function using `df['column'].apply(mapper_function)`

`df["date"]` basically gives your a pandas Series object, not an individual objects in the column.

Comment: You need to define a function that takes a date object and returns strftime of that object. You'll need to apply that function, not `time.strftime("...")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dt.floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) as follows:

```
df['date_fixed']= df['date'].dt.floor(freq='S')
```